# dynamically creating row in html table

Tags: javascript, html

Can i assign an ID to a  element, and then have java Script to add just the same row. I saw some scripts where we add they add row and cell separately, and then add  separately. Instead of this i have something like this

```
        <tr id="hourRecord1">
            <td><SELECT NAME="day">
                    <OPTION selected="selected">Sunday</option>
                    <OPTION>Monday</option>
                    <OPTION>Tuesday</option>
                    <OPTION>Wednesday</option>
                    <OPTION>Thursday</option>
                    <OPTION>Friday</option>
                    <OPTION>Saturday</option>
            </SELECT></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="openTime" size="10" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="closeTime" size="10" value=""></td>
        </tr>
```

and i want to use the ID to add a similar row. Can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
var oldrow = document.getElementById('hourRecord1'),
    newrow = oldrow.cloneNode(true);
newrow.id = ""; // can't have two elements with same ID, so delete the ID from newrow
oldrow.parentNode.insertBefore(newrow,oldrow.nextSibling);
```